# On mouse down function needs to be refreshed

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to know why the following code which gets generated upon clicking on a yes/no box does not work the first time it is performed. Upon clicking on it, the code gets executed but does not acknowledte the fact that the checkbox has been checked leaving me with a checked checkbox but not the proper result. Upon de-selecting it, the correct result is achieved, and then upon selecting it again, the code is performed correctly.

```
Private Sub cmdAccounting_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

If Me.cmdAccounting = 0 Then

    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!cost.Visible = True
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!Etichetta35.Visible = True
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!Etichetta37.Visible = True
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!Etichetta43.Visible = True
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!qty.Visible = True
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!tot.Visible = True
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!lineaAccounting1.Visible = True
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!lineaAccounting2.Visible = True
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!FileSaved.Visible = False
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!lblFileSaved.Visible = False
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!Favourite.Visible = False
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!lblFavourite.Visible = False
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!ln01.Visible = False
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!ln02.Visible = False
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!ln03.Visible = False
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!ln04.Visible = False
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!txtInfo.Visible = False
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!ln05.Visible = False
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!ln06.Visible = False

Else
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!cost.Visible = False
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!Etichetta35.Visible = False
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!Etichetta37.Visible = False
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!Etichetta43.Visible = False
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!qty.Visible = False
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!tot.Visible = False
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!lineaAccounting1.Visible = False
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!lineaAccounting2.Visible = False

    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!FileSaved.Visible = True
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!lblFileSaved.Visible = True
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!Favourite.Visible = True
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!lblFavourite.Visible = True
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!ln01.Visible = True
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!ln02.Visible = True
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!ln03.Visible = True
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!ln04.Visible = True
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!txtInfo.Visible = True
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!ln05.Visible = True
    Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!ln06.Visible = True

End If

Me.Form.Refresh
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to refresh, you must use `Clik` event and not `MouseDown`:

```
 Private Sub cmdAccounting_Click()
   If Me.cmdAccounting = 0 Then
     Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!cost.Visible = True
   Else
     Me![frmMasterListOfEventsDetailHistory].Form!cost.Visible = False
   End If
 End Sub
```

Your problem:
the state of the checkbox is changed after the `MouseDown` event, 
so your result is wrong,
and you must used `refresh`to see the good result...